# Trouble with getting access to an object's property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a trouble with getting access to an object's property.

Isn't it possible to get access to an object's property like this?

```
key["heading"]
```

key in the code above is a variable.

This code below is the code I'm working on right now.

```
alertHeading.on('blur', function(){

    var inputtedVal = $(this).val();
    var key = alertMode.val();

    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage) {

        var background = backgroundPage.background;

        //(1)This works fine.
        background.setStorage(key, {heading:inputtedVal});  
        console.log(background.getStorage(key));// Object {heading: "aaa"}

        //(2)This doesn't work.
        var alertObject = background.getStorage(key["heading"]);
        console.log(alertObject);// null. I'm expecting to get "aaa".

    });

})
```

I think I'm making a very simple mistake which comes from my lack of javascript knowledge.

Please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: what does `console.log(alertMode)` output?

Comment: it outputs like this. [input#alert-mode.switch, context: document, selector: "#alert-mode", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function…]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `key` isn't an object, it's a string. It is the return from `background.getStorage(key)` that is an object, so you can do this:

```
var alertObject = background.getStorage(key)["heading"]; // note () and [] placement

// OR, in two steps:
var alertObject = background.getStorage(key);
var heading = alertObject["heading"];
```

EDIT:

> *"I haven't understood why it's not an object but a string yet"*

Your `key` variable is set to the return from jQuery's `.val()` method:

```
var key = alertMode.val();
```

...which returns a string that is the value of the form element that it is called on. Add in a `console.log(key)` and you'll see.

Comment: Thanks!! it does work! I haven't understood why it's not an object but a string yet. But, I'll try to figure it out. I'm going to accept your answer but I need to wait for 7 more minutes until stack overflow let me do it.

Comment: Thank you for your edition. It helped me understand the problem.